# Play game Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock in Python for 10 times not return different result

Tags: python

I'm working on  Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock in Python game and I choose 2 players select random values
Then I want to play it for many times and get the result, but it just played once and print the data many times

```
class Action(IntEnum):
    Rock = 0
    Paper = 1
    Scissors = 2
    Lizard = 3
    Spock = 4

victories = {
    Action.Scissors: [Action.Lizard, Action.Paper],
    Action.Paper: [Action.Spock, Action.Rock],
    Action.Rock: [Action.Lizard, Action.Scissors],
    Action.Lizard: [Action.Spock, Action.Paper],
    Action.Spock: [Action.Scissors, Action.Rock]
}

def get_user_selection():
    selection = random.randint(0, len(Action) - 1)
    action = Action(selection)
    return action

def get_computer_selection():
    selection = random.randint(0, len(Action) - 1)
    action = Action(selection)
    return action

user_action = get_user_selection()
computer_action = get_computer_selection()

def determine_winner(user_action, computer_action):
    defeats = victories[user_action]
    if user_action == computer_action:
        print(f"Both players selected {user_action.name}. It's a tie!")
    elif computer_action in defeats:
        print(f"{user_action.name} beats {computer_action.name}! You win!")
    else:
        print(f"{computer_action.name} beats {user_action.name}! You lose.")
res=[]
for n in range(5):
        new = determine_winner(user_action, computer_action)
        res.append(new)
        print(res)
```

Result is
Spock beats Scissors! You lose.
[None]
Spock beats Scissors! You lose.
[None, None]
Spock beats Scissors! You lose.
[None, None, None]
Spock beats Scissors! You lose.
[None, None, None, None]
Spock beats Scissors! You lose.
[None, None, None, None, None]

I want to have a different result every run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only running get_user_selection() and get_computer_selection() once, then comparing them 5 times, move them into the for loop to repeat selections each time. Also to get the result you need to return a value from determine_winner() function, see below:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
from enum import IntEnum


class Action(IntEnum):
    Rock = 0
    Paper = 1
    Scissors = 2
    Lizard = 3
    Spock = 4

victories = {
    Action.Scissors: [Action.Lizard, Action.Paper],
    Action.Paper: [Action.Spock, Action.Rock],
    Action.Rock: [Action.Lizard, Action.Scissors],
    Action.Lizard: [Action.Spock, Action.Paper],
    Action.Spock: [Action.Scissors, Action.Rock]
}

def get_user_selection():
    selection = random.randint(0, len(Action) - 1)
    action = Action(selection)
    return action

def get_computer_selection():
    selection = random.randint(0, len(Action) - 1)
    action = Action(selection)
    return action



def determine_winner(user_action, computer_action):
    defeats = victories[user_action]
    if user_action == computer_action:
        print(f"Both players selected {user_action.name}. It's a tie!")
        return 'tie'
    elif computer_action in defeats:
        print(f"{user_action.name} beats {computer_action.name}! You win!")
        return 'win'
    else:
        print(f"{computer_action.name} beats {user_action.name}! You lose.")
        return 'lose'
res=[]
for n in range(5):
    user_action = get_user_selection()
    computer_action = get_computer_selection()
    new = determine_winner(user_action, computer_action)
    res.append(new)
```

outputs:

```
Paper beats Spock! You lose.
['lose']
Paper beats Rock! You win!
['lose', 'win']
Lizard beats Paper! You win!
['lose', 'win', 'win']
Paper beats Rock! You win!
['lose', 'win', 'win', 'win']
Scissors beats Paper! You lose.
['lose', 'win', 'win', 'win', 'lose']
```

Comment: supeeer :D works perfectly